# Is there a way to generate a documentation wiki for github from my XML documentation comments in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github, documentation, markdown, wiki

I want to generate API documentation for my open source project on Github. I'd like to create them automatically from my XML Documentation Comments in my C# projects. My feeble googling has turned up bubkiss. Is there a way to do this?

I'd prefer it be in Github-style [Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/).

Comment: Have you see nthis? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381/generating-documentation-from-c-sharp-xml-comments

Comment: Yes, but that's not quite what I'm looking for, I've used things like Sandcastle in the past, but I want to generate git up wiki markdown.

Comment: What about Doxygen?  Couldn't you take the doxygen output and set it up as a .nojekyll gh-pages branch on github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) to generate plain HTML and using that. Inevitably, I'll just write my own parser or a custom template for Sandcastle.

I didn't like the learning curve for Doxygen or QDoc.

Comment: Were you able to come up with any better solution?

Comment: Link is not valid now :(
Can you update it please?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an *online* C# XML doc to Markdown converter: http://varus.io/vsdoc-2-md/

It is based on @formixian's algorithm.

Comment: Nice work! I never realized that my gist became so popular!!!

Answer (score 7):

After searching around a bit, I found this gem of a gist:

[Generates Markdown from VS XML documentation file](https://gist.github.com/lontivero/593fc51f1208555112e0)

It prints to the C# XML -> markdown to the console. I'm sure it can be refined further, but this is a really great start. I've tested it, and it's totally working.

Comment: I did an implementation that gives better results at: https://gist.github.com/formix/515d3d11ee7c1c252f92

The resulting documentation looks like: https://github.com/formix/MegaCityOne/blob/master/MegaCityOne/doc/api.md

Comment: That actually is a lot better :)

Comment: @formix: That looks good, but it is a little difficult to tell if I am looking at a class, property or method.

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz: Is there any documentation for this? I'm not clear on the input? It doesn't appear to be reading a C# source file directly. Is there some process to generate an XML file from C# meta comments?

Comment: @JonathanWood That's a good point. I'll probably make it clearer in an upcoming version.

Comment: @JonathanWood - There doesn't seem to be any documentation that I know of, but if you look at the code, it's pretty clear that it's reading an XML file.

Comment: @JonathanWood - Sorry, I didn't answer your question completely. Yes, you can generate the XML documentation from your C# code. That's how you're generally able to view API descriptions for libraries you're using (if they include the XML file). In Visual Studio you go to `Project > Properties`, then in the properties window, select `Build`, and then in the middle of the window there are some output paths. One of them is the path where your XML documentation will be created.

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz: Thanks! I've posted a new GitHub project and it desperately needs documentation. I will try again.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Doxygen. By configuring Doxygen using the configure files and XSLT you can pretty much do anything with it. http://www.doxygen.nl/

Set the source files and output in the configuration files, then use XSLT to customize the output.

For Doxygen there is a parser tool (http://code.google.com/p/doxygenxmlparser/) already prepared to do much of the work with C#

if(youDoNotLikeThisIdea == true)
Another tool that is highly configurable would be QDoc (part of the Qt API) @ http://qt-project.org. Of course, using QDoc would require you to build Qt and QDoc in particular.

Good luck!

Comment: You could shorten the `if` statement by taking out the `== true` :)